# Haskell: No instance arising

Tags: haskell, types

Beginning with Haskell, I frequently encounter problems with types (and less helpful error messages of GHC). I defined following function:

```
ghci> let f x = floor x == x
ghci> :t f
f :: (Integral a, RealFrac a) => a -> Bool
```

which succeeds, but the invocation seams to be difficult:

```
ghci> let a = 1.1
ghci> f a

<interactive>:296:1:
    No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `f'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Double)
    In the expression: f a
    In an equation for `it': it = f a
ghci> let b = 2
ghci> f b

<interactive>:298:1:
    No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `f'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
    In the expression: f b
    In an equation for `it': it = f b
```

How to define the function correctly?

Comment: Make sure you always use a type signature when you define a function so the compiler knows exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Indeed, adding type signatures often dramatically improves GHC error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell doesn't do *any* automatic coercion between different numeric types so if you e.g. compare `x == y` then `x` and `y` have to have the exact same type (e.g. both are ints or both are floats).

Now, if you look at the type of `floor` it's

```
floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

Which means that you can only call it for fractional types and result type must be an integral type.

When you call `f 1.1` inside `f` you end up making the comparison

```
floor 1.1 == 1.1
```

But now you have a problem because `floor` can only return integral types and in order to make the comparison the result has to have the same type as `1.1` which is definitely not integral.

You need to define `f` as

```
let f x = fromIntegral (floor x) == x
```

The [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) call coerces the integral floor value back into a fractional value so that it can be compared with the original `x`.

Comment: A bit off topic: I wonder if that will be optimized in the case of e.g. a `Double->Double` conversion. I mean, it seems silly to convert `1e100` to `Integer` just to convert it back into a `Double`. This however seems the only way to perform the truncation.